# Filter with root and nested level attribute in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

Input :

```js
// First Array
const input1 = [{
    'name': "name1",
    'email': "emai2@email.com",
    'age': 10,
    'address': {
      'city': "city1"
    }
  },
  {
    'name': "name2",
    'email': "emai2@email.com",
    'age': 20,
    'address': {
      'city': "city2"
    }
  }
];

// Second Array
const input2 = [{
    'id': 1,
    'fullname': "name1",
    'emailaddress': "emai2@email.com",
    'age': 10,
    'address': {
      'city': "city1"
    }
  },
  {
    'id': 5,
    'name': "name2",
    'email': "emai55@email.com",
    'age': 20,
    'address': {
      'city': "city3"
    }
  }
];

const filter = [{
  "filter1Key": "name",
  "filter2Key": "address.city"
}];

const matchArray = [];
const newArray = [];
let filterInput = '';

const test1 = input1.filter((data) => input2.some((obj) => filter.every(key => data[key.filter1Key] === obj[key.filter2Key])));
console.log(test1);
```

Here I want to filter record by root level key as well as with nested level key .In this scenario root level key is name and  nested level key is city which is inside address If both will match those record should be filtered

Comment: what is the expected output? or is it 2 outputs for 2 inputs?

Answer (score 0):

You could use Lodash [`intersectionBy`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#intersectionBy) function to get the matching items between the 2 arrays.

As for the matching criterion, you could also use Lodash [`get`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#get) function, which understands the dot notation to access nested properties.

```js
// First Array
const input1 = [{
    'name': "name1",
    'email': "emai2@email.com",
    'age': 10,
    'address': {
      'city': "city1"
    }
  },
  {
    'name': "name2",
    'email': "emai2@email.com",
    'age': 20,
    'address': {
      'city': "city2"
    }
  }
];

// Second Array
const input2 = [{
    'id': 1,
    // 'fullname': "name1", // Typo?
    'name': "name1",
    'emailaddress': "emai2@email.com",
    'age': 10,
    'address': {
      'city': "city1"
    }
  },
  {
    'id': 5,
    'name': "name2",
    'email': "emai55@email.com",
    'age': 20,
    'address': {
      'city': "city3"
    }
  }
];

// You can directly specify all AND keyPaths
// in the filter array
const filter = [
  "name",
  "address.city"
];

const test1 = _.intersectionBy(
  input1,
  input2,
  (item) => JSON.stringify(filter.map(
    (keyPath) => _.get(item, keyPath)
  ))
);

console.log(test1); // Result: 1st item of input1 (matching name and address.city of 1st item of input2)
```

```html
<script src="
https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.21/lodash.min.js
"></script>
```

Note: I assume there is a typo in `input2` first item (`'fullname'` key should have been `'name'` for consistency with the other items).